Type Error: Assignment to const variable declaring a variable as let when importing a variable from another file
In JavaScript(Node.JS), I have made a config.js file like below for exporting a name variable:
Config.js
export let name ="ayush";

and I am importing the name variable in index.js file
index.js
import {name} from "./config.js";

name ="Rishabh"

console.log(name);

But I am getting Type Error:assignment to constant variable.
I have declared a variable as let, why am I still getting the above error?
I am trying to change the variable name in another file. but I am getting the error, not able to understand what JavaScript concept is missing like (import is only read only).

You’re really only exporting the value, not the let declaration. What are you trying to do here ultimately?

Actually I was working on another project, I have a given a dummy code here, basically I want to modified the name variable value , name variable should hold the value ="Rishabh".

@ayushsingh ,Do you only want to change the variable name or you want to change the value inside config.js?

value inside config.js

@ayushsingh,Please check I have posted my answer.

In JavaScript, imported bindings are read-only. You cannot change their value in the module where they are imported.
This is because exporting mutable variables can lead to unpredictable behavior and bugs.
If you want to share a common object, which also need to be mutable, export a const object and modify the properties of it instead.
config.js
export const obj = {
    name: 'xxx'
};

index.js
import {obj} from "./config.js";

obj.name ="Rishabh";

console.log(name);


Remember in your index.js file you are reassigning name variable imported from config.js file which is not allowed.
You should use an object instead of a primitive value, because properties of an object can be modified even when the object itself is imported as a constant.
Do this for Config.js
export let config = {
  name: "ayush"
};

Then do this for index.js
import { config } from "./config.js";

config.name = "Rishabh"; // modify the property of the object

console.log(config.name); // logs "Rishabh"

Try this I hope it will work.
